# tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn throws _NumericColumn' object has no attribute 'insert_transformed_feature

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow

Trying to execute the next code:

```
feature_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in df.columns.values]

classifier = tf.contrib.learn.SVM( example_id_column='example_id', feature_columns=feature_cols, l2_regularization=10.0)

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    x=pd.DataFrame(df),
    y=pd.Series(score),
batch_size=128,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False,
    queue_capacity=1000,
    num_threads=1,
    target_column='target'
    )

classifier.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=2000)
```

I am getting the next error:

> File "mlSVM.py", line 68, in 
>       classifier.fit(input_fn=input_fn, steps=2000)
>
> File "/home/walker/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py",
>   line 316, in new_func
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/walker/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py",
>   line 480, in fit
>       loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
>
> File "/home/walker/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py",
>   line 986, in _train_model
>       model_fn_ops = self._get_train_ops(features, labels)
>
> File "/home/walker/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py",
>   line 1202, in _get_train_ops
>       return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
>
> File
>   "/home/walker/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py",
>   line 1166, in _call_model_fn
>       model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features, labels, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/walker/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/linear.py", line 244, in sdca_model_fn
>       features.update(layers.transform_features(features, feature_columns))
>
> File
>   "/home/walker/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.py",
>   line 647, in transform_features
>       transformer.transform(column)
>
> File "/home/walker/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.py",
>   line 838, in transform
>       feature_column.insert_transformed_feature(self._columns_to_tensors)
>
> AttributeError: '_NumericColumn' object has no attribute
>   'insert_transformed_feature'

How could it be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you're mixing the SVM estimator from `tf.contrib` with the feature columns from core TensorFlow (`tf.feature_column.numeric_column`).

Try using the contrib version of the feature columns.  Replace `tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k)` with `tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(k)`.

[This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-move-from-tf-contrib-learn-estimator-to-core-tensorflow-tf-estimator-af07b2d21f34) gives some more context on why this is an issue.